# Error when starting watchman

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, watchman

hi when i want to start my app with 'react-native start', i get this error. Somebody know what to do? I tried to change the permission of the watchman folder and the project folder to chmod -R 777 'path'

```
Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph...watchman warning:  opendir(/home/t/react/testApp/android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com) -> Permission denied. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
Recrawled this watch 1 times, most recently because:
/home/t/react/testApp: dir missing from internal state
To resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /home/t/react/testApp ; watchman watch-project /home/t/react/testApp`

opendir(/home/t/react/testApp/android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com) -> Permission denied. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
Recrawled this watch 1 times, most recently because:
/home/t/react/testApp: dir missing from internal state
To resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /home/t/react/testApp ; watchman watch-project /home/t/react/testApp`

Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this script from your the root directory of your source - usually fixes my watchman woes:

[React Native Clean](https://gist.github.com/jesussteve/45a9251e4d1419283086379e069aed56)

You can run as follows from the directory where your `package.json` is stored:

```
# Download
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jesussteve/45a9251e4d1419283086379e069aed56/raw/fb0107399b684dad3fecbc1af478575bfe0cb65f/react-native-clean.sh

# Set permissions
chmod a+x react-native-clean.sh

# Run script from current path
./react-native-clean.sh ./
```

Would advise to back up first before running just in case.

Comment: The link is broken. Please post the actual content on StackOverflow to avoid these kind of problems.